# Rails, Capistrano, Puma. Проблемма с запуском после деплоя

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Сайт на `RoR 5.0.3` `Deploy` с использованием `Capistrano` Сервер `Nginx + Puma 3.9. ОС Ubuntu 16.04` При запуске `puma` на продакшене после деплоя

> bundle exec cap production puma:restart **ошибка** We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Логи `production.log` и `puma.erro.log` чистые. Если запускать в ручную из

```
current/ rails s -e production
```

то на 3000 потру работает все нормлаьно.

**Capfile:**

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/secrets_yml'

require 'capistrano/puma'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma

require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**deploy.rb**

```
server '11.11.11.11', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@gitlab.com:username/appname.git'
set :application,     'appname'
set :user,            'deployer'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/var/www/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end


  desc 'Runs rake db:seed for SeedMigrations data'
  task :seed => [:set_rails_env] do
    on primary fetch(:migration_role) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, "db:seed"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  after 'deploy:migrate', 'deploy:seed'

  desc 'Runs rake assets:precompile'
  task :precompile do
    on roles(:app) do
      if DEPLOY_ENV == 'production'
        execute("cd #{DEPLOY_TO_DIR}/current && RAILS_ENV=production rvm #{ruby_string} do rake assets:precompile")
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream puma {
    server unix:///var/www/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  server_name appname;

  root /var/www/appname/current/public;
  access_log /var/www/appname/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/appname/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Как отловить и исправить ошибку?

Comment: Something went wrong это 500 Internal Server Error. Смотрите логи приложения.

Comment: >>Логи production.log и puma.erro.log чистые

Comment: Значит, логи настроены неверно. 500 всегда сопровождается стектрейсом.

Comment: возможно, но при "ручном" запуске логи пишутся нормально. как раз в этом и пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Меня настораживает только то, что вы при ручном запуске явно указываете `-e production`. Если у вас задана переменная среды `RAILS_ENV=production`, то это не нужно. А если она у вас не задана, скорее всего приложение у вас пытается стартануть в `development` без части нужных зависимостей. И в этом случае неудивительно, что оно падает.

Comment: да, вы правы. если не указывать -e production то пытается стартовать в development.

Comment: добаивл переменную окружения. в ручном теперь как надо запускается. но при деплое пробелмы те же( в логах никаких ошибок критических только info, debug, warning от burbon.